# How to install product only once on 64-bit OS?

Tags: wix, installation, 64-bit

I have 2 installer versions for the same product:

1. 32-bit version
2. 64-bit version (it is copy of 1st with minimal changes)

They work ok, but now I can install both versions on 64-bit OS.

The question is: how to allow installation only one version of product on one machine?

Comment: This should give you a hint: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/block_install_on_os.htm

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to be able to install the 32bit version on a 64bit O/S if the 64bit version isn't installed or should the 32bit version only be installed on a 32bit O/S?

Depending on your answer, you can either author the 32bit install with a LaunchCondition that uses the VersionNT64 property to make sure it's not a 64bit O/S  ( no such authoring in the 64bit install since MSI won't let a 64bit install run on a 32bit platform )  or you'll have to use the Uprade table with the detect only attribute to pull in the existance of a mutually exclusive product and uset hat in the LaunchCondition.

Comment: Yes, to install the 32bit version on a 64bit O/S if the 64bit version isn't installed  OR  to install the 64bit version on a 64bit O/S if the 32bit version isn't installed. I.e to prevent the 32bit and 64bit to be installed on the same machine at teh same time.